# Skipping pseudo-filesystems when doing find/exec

Tags: find

Let me be clear about this. I want to do a find over multiple filesystems.

What I wish to do is skip pseudo-filesystems. Other than `-prune`, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to exclude just sysfs and procfs, or anything that's not a permanent on-disk filesystem such as tmpfs, ramfs, and FUSE?

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts, almost all of which include `-prune` (why do you want to avoid this?):

- If you have a consistent and known set of local filesystem types, use something like `find / \( -fstype rootfs -o -fstype ext4 -o -prune \) ...others... -print`
- If you have a known set of pseudo-filesystem types, use something like `find / \( -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype udev \) -prune -o \( ...others... -print \)`
- If you have a known set of mountpoints for pseudo-filesystems, use something like `find / \( -path '/dev' -o -path '/run' \) -prune -o \( ...others... -print \)`
- If you know the mountpoints of the filesystems you *do* want to search, use something like `find / /home /var -mount ...others... -print`